# Kubernetes does not respect initialDelaySeconds when starting up

Tags: kubernetes

I have configured a `pod` as follows:

```
  livenessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 60
    periodSeconds: 10
    failureThreshold: 3
  readinessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 60
    periodSeconds: 10
    failureThreshold: 3
```

Readiness and Liveness probes are tcp-socker based

```
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: {{ .Values.port }}
            initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
            periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.periodSeconds }}
            failureThreshold: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.failureThreshold }}
```

However, when I deploy, the pod is marked almost immediately as `failed` and goes in `Error` --> `CrashLoopBackOff`.
The pod checks a redis connection (which does indeed need a little time to become ready).

And of course I see the connection errors in my pod's logs

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to redis-master:6379. Connection refused.
```

Why is the pod being marked in `Error` / CLBO so eagerly, way before `initialDelaySeconds: 60`?

Here is the pod's `yaml` dump regarding the probes (I increased the `initialDelaySecond` to both probes to 100, but still the same...)

```
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      initialDelaySeconds: 100
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      tcpSocket:
        port: 9898
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: mycontainer
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9898
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      initialDelaySeconds: 100
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      tcpSocket:
        port: 9898
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated.

Now pod can get failed because of `CrashLoopBackOff` even before starting the probes. **This is the concept here**. It can occur if you set the container `restartPolicy` to `Never`.

You can see the pod logs or events for getting the reason of pod failure (can use `kubectl describe <pod>`)